# Ejecutar script unicamente cuando se cierra la venta del navegador

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, script

quiero actualizar un campo en mi base de datos cuando el usuario cierra la ventana del navegador. esto para controlar si el usuario esta "ONLINE" u "OFFLINE" después investigar un poco llegue a este fragmento de cogido JS que me funciona muy bien:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(){
    $.ajax({url: '../Procesos/cierra_nav.php?var=<?php echo $_SESSION['Id']; ?>'}); 
};
```

el problema es que también se ejecuta cuando se refresca el navegador, yo necesito que se ejecute únicamente al cerrar la ventana.

agradezco de antemano si me pueden ayudar con algún código o tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Ayudate con la navigation type, con ello, sabes si es recarga, vuelves por historial... lo añades para descartarlos en un if
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 1){
   //es recarga
}
```